# Biblioteca ion_auth codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa tarde Devs!

Estou clonando um sistema do github para aproveitar partes do código.
O Sistema já vêm com login de adm inserido no banco de dados, porém não sei a senha. Quero criar um novo administrador.

Sei que tenho que usar a função create_user() que fica dentro da pastas controllers o arquivo auth.php.

Minha dúvida é como faço para invocar esse método.
Segue link da aplicação:
https://github.com/Cubo-design/sistema_cliente

Em pesquisas vi que tenho que incluir a biblioteca Ion Auth, como posso estar fazendo essa inclusão.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode encontrar a função create_user() em: https://github.com/Cubo-design/sistema_cliente/blob/master/application/controllers/Auth.php

Mas eu acredito que você também deseje alterar as configurações de database, que você pode encontrar em: https://github.com/Cubo-design/sistema_cliente/blob/master/application/config/database.php

Eu espero ter ajudado de alguma maneira!

Comment: Bom dia! Obrigado pela ajuda Paulo!